# how to find app version installed in user's mobile using php webservice

Tags: php, android, ios, web-services, codeigniter

I'm working on a web service of both android and iOS. I'm using codeigniter framework for the same. At a certain point I want to know which version of app is installed in user's mobile. I just want to track version's history to remove and add new features. There is nothing written in mobile apps to do so. So I want to do it with webservice or with php. Please provide me a valid solution to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in Activity you can use `getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName` for get appVersionName and Code also as same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't figure it out from the server.  What you can do is send a special header with every request from your app with the version number, and track the number of requests from different versions through that.